# Nondeterministic finite automaton & DFA

Tags: dfa, nfa

I'm having an exam on Friday and i need to know if the following exercise its correct, because our dear professor won't put solutions to our exercises, like everybody else does so we can test if it is correct or not. I need to know if the algorithm that i used it is correct.

Below is an IMG of an NFA diagram and the second image is where i convert it to DFA (it is hand written).

Here are the exercise: [Exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLe9K.png)
Here is how i solved it: [Solved exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dywj.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's correct. Good job! You have followed the text book way to convert to DFA. And to answer the further question, "C" is a state that is not accessible in the DFA when you start at the start-state.

Comment: Thank you! No i did not follow his lecture, he's doing differently, and for the second question its {A,B,C}